# spring roo with hades addon

Tags: spring-roo, osgi-bundle

I am trying to install hades bundle in my roo.

I am following this article
java.dzone.com/articles/playi...-roo-and-hades

while executing

1. `osgi install --url http://hades.synyx.org/static/roo/re....0.RELEASE.jar`
2. `osgi start --url http://hades.synyx.org/static/roo/re....0.RELEASE.jar`

First runs fine, but in 2nd command it is throwing this error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.synyx.ha
```

des.roo.addon [75]: Unable to resolve 75.0: missing requirement [75.0] package;
(&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.entity)(v ersion>=1.1.0))

Can someone please help it out.

Thanks